# Vue deep watch prop

Tags: vue.js

In my component, I have a computed property

```
members() {
  return (this.club.properties || []).map(property => {
    const user = Object.assign({}, property.user, property, { user: undefined })
    return user
  })
},
```

This computed property is been given as a v-bind on another component

```
<MyComponent :members="members" :club="club"/>
```

The MyComponent component displays all the members, when I am adding a new 
property though

```
this.club.properties.push(someProperty)
```

The MyComponent is not been rerendered I have to refresh the page in order to have the new property to be rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make deep copy to make Vue reactive

```
this.club.properties.push(someProperty)
this.club = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.club))
```

This is common [Vue reactivity problem](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

Comment: Yes, I also think this is the solution, as in the `club` object the `properties` key is pointing to another location in memory, so I think you need to make `this.club` aware of the change.

Comment: vue does not let me do that because club is a prop.

Comment: Then you need to emit event to parent and change `this.club` in parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can update the club properties one at a time using `Vue.set(object, propertyName, value)` to make it reactive.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats